# PHP SFTP/SSH transfer

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, transfer

I posted a question a little while ago but I asked about FTP, which is the wrong question (doh!). I need to automatically transfer images (e.g. test.jpg) from one server to another using SFTP/SSH.

Could someone please explain how I would do this? I am completely new to this kind of thing so as much information as possible would be really appreciated.

Thanks for any help

```
<?php

$local_file = "http://localhost/ftptest/logo.png";
$remote_file = "/logo.png";

exec("scp $local_file username:pass@***.**.238.87:$remote_file");

?>
```

edit:

in the end I found that this works:

```
<?php

     include('Net/SFTP.php');

     $image = 'logo.jpg'; //image to be uploaded - needs to be in the same directory as this script e.g. just logo.jpg

     $image_contents = file_get_contents($image); // location of image to be uploaded

     $sftp = new Net_SFTP('***.**.**.**'); // server address to connect to
     if (!$sftp->login('***', '***')) { // server login details
         exit('Login Failed');
     }

     echo $sftp->pwd();
     $sftp->put($image, $image_contents); // upload a file $image with the image contents.

?>
```

Couldn't get the SSH working but hopefully this will help someone in the future :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is too often the case here, you've not provided much information about what you are trying to achieve nor the constraints.

Where does the image originate from? How quickly does it need to be replicated? Are the servers equivalent nodes in a cluster?

Since both servers are already talking HTTP, why use a different protocol for transferring content?

As Antonio suggests you could simply exec scp - but this is only going to work if you've got key pairs set up.

A more flexible solution (assuming ssh is a requirement) would be to use the [ssh bindings in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php)

Comment: Hi symcbean, I've had a look at this but I'm struggling to understand what to do. So far I have downloaded the phpseclib files and put them in the same directory as my PHP script, and then I have added include('/Net/SSH2.php'); to the script file. I've also downloaded openssl but I don't know what to do with that, could you explain please? Thanks

Comment: I did phpinfo() and it says that openssl is already enabled. The error I'm getting is 'Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()', does that mean I've installed the phpseclib files wrongly?

Comment: It means you've not got the ssh2 PECL installed. How you about gettnig it depends on which version of PHP you are using, what OS you are running on, and where you got the PHP from.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to handle this is to call PHP [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and execute a unix scp call.

```
exec("scp $local_file user1@somehost:$remote_file");
```

Comment: Hi antonio, I have updated my question with the code I have but it is not transferring the image to the 2nd server. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Symcbean is correct, I forgot to mention that you need to have your key pairs set to authenticate the scp. Setting that up does make my answer a bit more complicated. Look at symcbean's solution, that might be a better way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ssh2_scp_send](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-scp-send.php):

```
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');

ssh2_scp_send($connection, '/local/filename', '/remote/filename', 0644);
```